# LM317 TO-220 heat sinking: Junction to case or junction to pad?

Tags: heatsink, lm317

I have some [LM317](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm317) ICs (TO-220) that I'm using on a power supply. I'm trying to figure out the heat sink values necessary to keep the IC under safe operation.

All of my requirements are with 700 mA current, however Vi-Vo varies. For an example, the maximum Vi-Vo I have is 12 V. So the power dissipated is 8.4 W.

So I got the following thermal resistance values from the data sheet:

> Junction to ambient: 19 ℃\W
>   Junction to case: 17 ℃\W
>   Junction to pad: 3 ℃\W

I'm using a thermal tape to fasten it to a heatsink. I can do the calculations myself, but my problem is that I'm confused if I should consider the junction to case or junction to pad thermal resistance value? The junction to case resistance seems too high. If I use that for heatsinking calculations, I find that no heatsink can save me from overheating it. But junction to pad gives me hope.

Which one of the following is correct?

- Junction temperature = Ambient temperature + Pd * (Junction to case + thermal interface material + heatsink thermal resistance)
- Junction temperature = Ambient temperature + Pd * (Junction to pad + thermal interface material + heatsink thermal resistance)**

I'd like to avoid swithcing regulators as much as possible, I already have these ICs and switching regulators will add unwanted complexity here.

Comment: If you don't solder the LM317 into the PCB, then use junction to case thermal resistance value. btw the heatsink you need is quite big. If you want to use a 2mm aluminium plate it will be not less than 16x16 cm. I suggest to reduce Vi-Vo or use a series resistor.

Comment: @GRTech, I'm going to use the LM317 like this, except with a heatsink. Is this what you mean by soldering it into PCB?http://www.nabilkarami.com/projects/images/lm317%201.JPG

Comment: θjp usually refered when soldering pad directly to pcb copper. However the θjc given as 17 ℃\W it is unusual for TO-220 packages, which ia typically 5 ℃\W. Anyway standard PCB copper can provide thermal resistance not less than about 20 ℃\W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the note just below the thermal data table from that datasheet:

> For packages with exposed thermal pads, such as QFN, PowerPAD™, or PowerFLEX™, \$\theta_{JP}\$ is defined as the thermal resistance between the die junction and the bottom of the exposed pad.

The way I interpret that:

[image: TO-220 with case and pad labeled]

So if you are attaching the heatsink in the normal way, on the back, against the pad, use the junction to pad thermal resistance.

Comment: Thanks! So how else would someone use the heatsink? The junction to case seems essentially useless.

Comment: Take a look here http://www.acoustica.org.uk/t/naim/datasheets&pix/voltage_regulators/lm317t.pdf in bottom of page 3 (T package)